# How to make submenu disappear on click without using JS?

Tags: html, css

Looking at this example:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_subnav.asp

I would like to make the submenu disappear on click without using Javascript.  Is this possible?

It can be made to appear on hover without JS.  The idea would be to hide the submenu once a submenu item is clicked.  For example:

[image: HTML/CSS submenu example]

If you click "Package" the entire submenu and red background should not be shown.

**EDIT 1:**
I should add that I experimented using `:has` and `:target` in various combinations to set change it to `display: none`.  That did not work.

Comment: [Is that like what you want?](https://jsfiddle.net/trvL6zub/)

Comment: No.  In your example, when you click "Child 1" or "Child 2" the menu should close down to the base menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think that technically the answer to your question is yes, it is possible, but actually no - at least not in a way your page will continue functioning normally afterwards. Let me explain:

If you were to use anchor elements for our subnav links/buttons you could use a combination of the the `:visited` and `:has` pseudo classes to set the submenu's display to none (`display: none;`) and the main menu's color to the original color. However, I believe this will mean you won't be able to make the submenu appear again unless you were to somehow cancel the "visited" status of the anchor element that was clicked which if possible, will most certainly include the use of JS anyway...

Comment: I just edited the question to note that I did try `:has` and also `:target` as ideas in various combinations.  Can't get it to work.  The other interesting thing is that I used JS to change `display:` to `none` and it didn't work.  When I `console.log()` the display property it always comes up `none`.  This leads me to believe that `:hover` causes things to behave a bit differently.  It triggers when you hover, yes, yet, when you are in the submenu the property seems to be back to `none` even though you can see the submenu.  I need to review the code to make sure I didn't mess it up.